# Why is $\;n^2-\frac{n^2}{2} =\frac{n^2}{2}\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, exponentiation

Could someone please expand on how to get from $\;\displaystyle\left( n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}\right)\;$ to $\;\left(\dfrac{n^2}{2}\right)\;?\;$

I can't seem to wrap my head around that.

Comment: If you have one bread and you take away half of it, then you remain with...?

Comment: This probably needs more than five answers. One more effort!

Comment: @azimut I find your comment confusing, given that most breads are not square.

Comment: @julien Okay, if you insist

Comment: Now, I wonder why I suspect you guys are responding to a wind-up ......

Comment: Visually, take a piece of paper of size n by n, total area is n^2. Now fold it to half and remove it. What's the total area?

Comment: This may be one of the few questions where removing an inappropriate tag would constitute a substantive hint.  The "powers" in the question are irrelevant to the solution, as some of the answers have pointed out, and ignoring the powers makes things clearer.

Comment: @julien Ok, I've made it an even eleven.

Comment: I don't believe the result unless I see it proven via $\mathbb{N}$-induction using $\text{Nats}$ within *Homotopy Type Theory*.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Do you think we should add the ring-theory (or field-theory) tag to give another hint. After all, all this takes is $2$ to be a unit.

Comment: By golly! That looks exactly like the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem!!!

Comment: With due respect to the 5 users who voted to close the question, it  really is not "difficult to tell what is being asked here."

Comment: Closing as *Too localized* would be a better reason. Better yet, seeing the large number of redundant and/or frivolous answers, users could flag for a mod to lock the post. Locking is a common way to prevent accumulation of off-topic content on the site.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed.  How is this any different than if OP asked for a step to be clarified in a proof?  Just because the fact solicited is elementary doesn't make it "not a real question."

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I suspect the actual reason why it was closed has to do with the number of answers which are not real, especially their increasing number with respect to time.

Comment: Seems like that's what locking is for.

Comment: @user672009: try induction on $n$.

Comment: I agree with @Alexander: the closure is puzzling. The question is now going through deletion and undeletion cycles. which is even more absurd. This seems to reflect some bias against elementary questions, which greatly saddens me. The charter of this site is to welcome mathematical questions at *all* levels. I encourage everyone to think back to the time when you were first learning these elementary topics, and to consider how great it would be to have had access to the expertise of this forum. This is esp. helpful to those who may not have easy access to good schools or libraries.

Comment: I have locked this question due to a deletion war.  Continued meta discussion should take place [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16273/12952).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$n^2 = \dfrac{2n^2}{2}$$ $$\dfrac{2 n^2}{2} - \dfrac{n^2}{2} = \dfrac{2n^2 - n^2}{2}= \dfrac{n^2}{2}$$

In short, for any $X$: $\;(X = x; X = n^2; \text{ or}\;X = n^{917})\;\text{etc.}:\;$ $${\bf two}\text{ halves of X}\;- \;{\bf one} \text{ half of X}\; = \;{\bf one} \text{ half of X}$$

Answer (score 25):

This reduces to proving that $1-\frac 12 = \frac 12$. In order to do this, expand $1$ into the geometric series $$1=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^i},$$ and divide both sides by $2$ to get $$\frac 12=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{i+1}}=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^i}.$$ It follows that $$1-\frac 12 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^i}-\frac 1{2^1}=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^{i}}=\frac 12.$$

Comment: Sorry but this is also an attention-seeking answer.

Comment: @julien: Exactly, my comment on the other answer was sarcasm. ;)

Comment: Ha, ha! I was not totally sure.

Answer (score 23):

$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\ \end{array}\hspace{15pt}-\hspace{15pt}\begin{array}{cccc}\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}&\color{blue}{\star}\\\end{array}\hspace{15pt}=\hspace{15pt}\begin{array}{cccc}\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}&\color{red}{\star}\\\end{array}$$

$$ $$

Comment: This only proves the special case $n=8$. How might we proceed for other $n$?

Comment: The generalization to even $n$ is somewhat straightforward, but to odd $n$ is nontrivial. :-)

Answer (score 16):

Did you know that
$$x-\frac{x}{2}=\frac{x}{2}$$
whatever $x$ you take?

Answer (score 8):

We proceed by induction on $n$. The base case for $n = 0$ is $0^2 - \frac{0^2}{2} = 0 =\frac{0^2}{2}$, which follows from the fact that $0$ is the additive identity in $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose the claim holds for some $n = k$. Now
\begin{aligned}
(k+1)^2 - \frac{(k+1)^2}{2} &= k^2 + 2k + 1 - \frac{k^2}{2} - \frac{2k}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\ 
&= \color{blue}{\left ( k^2 - \frac{k^2}{2} \right )} + k + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \color{blue}{\frac{k^2}{2}} + k + \frac{1}{2} \quad \color{blue}{\text{(hypothesis)}} \\
&= \frac{k^2 + 2k + 1}{2} \\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2}{2}.
\end{aligned}
This concludes the inductive step, so our claim holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe an ancient greek-style of answer can be fun to read.

Let $A$ be the square with lenght of side $n$. Thererefore the area of $A$ is $n \cdot n = n^2$. Now draw one of the two diagonals. Note that the sum of the areas of the two right triangles you create (call it $B,C$) is equal to the area of $A$, and they have the same area, because they have two equal legs and the right angle between. Consider, for example $B$: the area of it is $\frac{n \cdot n}{2}$. So if you take from $A$ of area $n^2$, $B$ of area $\frac{n^2}{2}$ there is still the other, $C$ of area $\frac{n^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

$$x-\frac x2=\frac x2$$ Take from something its half and you're left with half of it

Answer (score 3):

That equation is saying
 $$n - \text{ half of } n =\text{ half of } n$$

If you substitute n for integers it's quite easy to see why it works.

$$1 - 1/2 = 1/2$$
$$2 - 2/2 = 2/2$$

Comment: This would be a better answer if you used some variable other than $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then $x\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}=\left(x-\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\dfrac{x}{2}$.

Comment: I can't say this is very enlightening. Could I also conclude that "If $(1 - \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ then $(1 - \frac{1}{x}) = \frac{1}{x}$."?

Comment: @TMM Do you know distributive laws?

Comment: @GastónBurrull I changed a word from your answer. I hope you don't mind. Maybe an intermediate step might be useful, to show the application of the distributive law.

Comment: If you added the step $x\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)$, this would be the most understandable  proof of this fact. From my perspective at least.

Comment: @Gaston: Of course I know what you mean. But if the user who asked the question does not know why $x - x/2 = x/2$, he also may now know what you did to go from $1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ to $x - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Simple arithmetic:
\begin{equation}
n^2 - \dfrac{n^2}{2} = n^2(1 - \dfrac{1}{2}) = n^2(\dfrac{1}{2}) = \dfrac{1}{2}n^2 = \dfrac{n^2}{2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting half of something yields half of that thing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n= \sin x$, so that $n^2 = \sin^{2} x = 1- \cos^{2} x$. Thus
$$
n^{2}- \frac{n^{2}}{2} = 1-\cos^{2} x - \frac{1-\cos^{2}x}{2}.
$$

Multiplying both sides by $2$ yields

$$
2n^{2} - n^{2} = 2-2\cos^{2} x - (1-\cos^{2}x) = 2-2\cos^{2} x - 1 +\cos^{2}x = 1 - \cos^{2} x = \sin^{2} x = n^{2}.
$$

Now dividing both sides by $2$ gives

$$
n^{2} - \frac{n^{2}}{2} = \frac{n^{2}}{2}.
$$

Comment: $n=\sin x$ has not sense if $n>1$.

Comment: @GastónBurrull Prove it.

Comment: Do you know that $|\sin x|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: @GastónBurrull I know that the government wants you to think that.

Comment: I didnt understood your joke.

Comment: @GastónBurrull This proof is perfectly valid. The range of $\sin$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is the whole of $\mathbb{C}$. It attains in particular every $n^2$. And $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$ on $\mathbb{C}$ too.

Comment: @julien thanks, but I think this answer also has circular reasoning

to proving that $2n^2-n^2=n^2$ he is using that $-2\cos^2x+\cos^2x=-\cos^2x$ I dont understand what is the point of this answer.

Comment: Hmmm...I very much doubt that whoever asked this question knows what complex numbers are, let alone complex functions...or even trigonometry.

Comment: @DonAntonio assuming reader knows complex number system and trigonometric complex functions, Is this a really valid answer? looks circular.

Comment: @GastónBurrull It's only a joke answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio As you can notice, I'm having a hard time taking this whole thread very seriously...

Comment: @GastónBurrull, it really doesn't after reading your comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio seriously?

Comment: Hehe...yes, @GastónBurrull: seriously ! I did read this answer paying very little attention and only until you noticed that the answer uses what must be proved I did, so even if the OP knows trig. and comp. numbers this answer doesn't work.

Comment: this topic really confuses me, also Ethan answer. I like to know if this phenomenon always occur when we deal with a trivial question...

Comment: @GastónBurrull How is using $-2\cos^2x+\cos^2x=-\cos^2x$ more circular than using $x-x/2=x/2$ or $2n^2-n^2=n^2$? The only important thing here is $1-1/2=1/2$. Every approach uses an equivalent form of that.

Comment: @GastónBurrull The phenomenon being that people feel motivated to post jokes as answers when the question is trivial? I suspect it has to do with the attention-seeking nature of these people. On the other hand, my answer is completely serious and hides no circularity.

Comment: @DonAntonio Just curious: why do you say this answer does not work, as opposed to other ones?

Comment: Because there's a circular argument in it, @Julien: the answerer wrote $$-2\cos^2x+\cos^2x=-\cos^2x$$in the middle of his post, which is just the same he's trying to prove.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's not what I read. He is proving that $2n^2-n^2=n^2$. Using this particular form of $n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}$ with $\cos$. Or using $2-1=1$ when proving $1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ would be circular as well.

Comment: Well @julien, I see it that way. The gist here is that the OP is apparently confused because of the squared $\,n\,$ and, it seems to be, he has it clear what happens when one uses simple fractions or even a variable $\,x\,$ .

Answer (score 2):

We want to prove that $n^2 - \frac{n^2}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2}$. In order to better understand what we want to do, let us simplify this equation a little bit by adding $\frac{n^2}{2}$ to both sides. We get $n^2 = \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2}$. So in order to solve the problem, we just need to show that $\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2} = n^2$. In order to show that these two things are equal, let's start with the left hand side and show that it equal to the right hand side. Since we know how to add fractions with the same denominator, we get 
$$\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2} = \frac{2n^2}{2} = \frac{2}{2}n^2= n^2$$
Now we're done!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $n^2=n^2$.

Hence $n^2=\frac{2n^2}{2}$
$$\implies n^2=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n^2}2$$
$$ \implies n^2- \frac{n^2}2=\frac{n^2}2$$
 as we wanted.

Comment: All you've shown is that **if** $n^{2} - \frac{n^{2}}{2} = \frac{n^{2}}{2}$ holds, then something 'obviously true' holds.

Comment: yeah you're right edit will be made

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you consider an integer division (so called [Euclidian division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)) the proposition becomes: 
$$
n^2 - \frac{n^2}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2} + \text{mod}{(n^2,2)}
$$

Indeed, by definition of the Euclidian division of the integer $n^2$ by the integer $2$, one has: 
$$
n^2 = 2\times\frac{n^2}{2} + \text{mod}{(n^2,2)}
$$
where $\text{mod}{(a,b)}$ denotes the remainder of the euclidian division of an integer $a$ by an integer $b$.

Now, by (cleverly enough) remarking that the term $2\times \frac{n^2}{2}$ equals to $\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2}$ one can write: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
n^2 &= 2\times\frac{n^2}{2} + \text{mod}{(n^2,2)} \\
n^2 &= \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \text{mod}{(n^2,2)} \\
\Leftrightarrow n^2 - \frac{n^2}{2}&= \frac{n^2}{2} + \text{mod}{(n^2,2)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
that ends the proof ;)